# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I am using a cxf webservice which uses local transport and accessing the webservice from java application.
Webservice is  reading a file and sending through webservice call. I am using the byte size as 512. Suppose the file size is 1200. First two attempt of retrieving the file is success and for the last chunk i am getting org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content.

Here chunk represents 512 bytes. I am converting bytes to string and returning from web service.In the last chunk only 16 byte value is filled and remaining are filled with zeros.
Any help will be appreciated. 
I am using cxf webservice 2.7.5, jdk1.7 ,Redhat Linux.

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:808)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:629)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:157)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:800)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1592)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1490)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
        at $Proxy62.getJobLog(Unknown Source)
        at com.java.process.AClass.getMessage(AClass.java:468)
        at com.java.process.AClass.getXXXX(AClass.java:156)
        at com.java.process.AClass.main(CLIClientStartup.java:409)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,1]]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:769)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:94)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$1.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:797)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:795)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructNullCharException(StreamScanner.java:630)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwInvalidSpace(StreamScanner.java:660)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readTextPrimary(BasicStreamReader.java:4576)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2879)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:196)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
        ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/)

> The problem that causes these XmlExceptions is that the data being
>   read or loaded contains characters that are illegal according to the
>   XML specifications. Almost always, these characters are in the ASCII
>   control character range (think whacky characters like null, bell,
>   backspace, etc). These aren’t characters that have any business being
>   in XML data; they’re illegal characters that should be removed,
>   usually having found their way into the data from file format
>   conversions, like when someone tries to create an XML file from Excel
>   data, or export their data to XML from a format that may be stored as
>   binary.

And an example for sanitizing the data before unmarshal.
[Error about invalid XML characters on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362302/error-about-invalid-xml-characters-on-java)

Maybe you should use something out of the box for transferring files, like MTOM
[check here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html)

Or you could use [CDATA syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193944/jaxb-marshalling-unmarshalling-with-cdata) to wrap the content, so the part that evaluates to null 
will be received as literal.

Comment: thanks for your response. The above exception is because of string contains zeros in the last chunk. In the last continous zeros make null[as in ascii/utf-8] so it is throwing and exception like this.

Comment: So those zeros are part of your content? What about using MTOM to send your file? Maybe that could be a solution?

Comment: Check my update. Maybe CDATA syntax could be a solution for your problem?

Comment: CDATA does not make invalid characters valid. They will still make the XML fail validation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties and change the project encoding to UTF-8.
Also use the following for marshaller and unmarchaller

```
    private static void exportToXML(JAXBContext ctx , Object obj , OutputStream stream) throws Exception{
    try {
        Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        m.marshal(obj, stream);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

private static Object importXML(JAXBContext ctx , String xmlStr) throws Exception {
    try {           
        Unmarshaller m = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return m.unmarshal(is);

    } catch (Throwable e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```