# I can't figure out why I am getting an "invalid XML character error"

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I don't understand why this error is popping up as I've debugged and gone through my source code multiple times now. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/color"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HEX: \nRGB"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thats the .XML file

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mResultTv;
    View mColorView;

    Bitmap bitmap;

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "SetTextI18n"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mResultTv = findViewById(R.id.resultTv);
        mColorView = findViewById(R.id.colorView);

        mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);



        mImageView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();

                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                int r = Color.red(pixel);
                int g = Color.green(pixel);
                int b = Color.blue(pixel);

                String hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(pixel);

                mColorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));

                mResultTv.setText("RGB: " + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + "\nHEX: " + hex);
                Log.d("SOMIL KEY", String.valueOf(r));

                }
                return true;
            });

    }
}
```

This is the .java file

The error I'm facing: Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

I've combed through stack exchange as well as a lot of other forums and can't find a good answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2362369/14419

Comment: Have already seen this, tried implementing all of the solutions, none worked for me

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure the parser doesn't lie...